# Need assistance with determining which button was pressed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

I'm using the complex_example.py included in the customkinter download.  The code runs fine, but I just can't figure out how to tell what button was pushed self.sidebar_button_1, self.sidebar_button_2 or self.sidebar_button_3 as they all return the same message "sidebar_button click".

I'll admit that I know way more about COBOL and CICS then I do PYTHON, and I'm still trying to learn.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("CustomTkinter complex_example.py")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="CustomTkinter", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.sidebar_button_event)
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        self.scaling_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="UI Scaling:", anchor="w")
        self.scaling_label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.scaling_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame, values=["80%", "90%", "100%", "110%", "120%"],
                                                               command=self.change_scaling_event)
        self.scaling_optionemenu.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 20))

        # create main entry and button
        self.entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self, placeholder_text="CTkEntry")
        self.entry.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")

        self.main_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, fg_color="transparent", border_width=2, text_color=("gray10", "#DCE4EE"))
        self.main_button_1.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 20), sticky="nsew")

        # create textbox
        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, width=250)
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")

        # create tabview
        self.tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self, width=250)
        self.tabview.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")
        self.tabview.add("CTkTabview")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 2")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 3")
        self.tabview.tab("CTkTabview").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure grid of individual tabs
        self.tabview.tab("Tab 2").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.optionmenu_1 = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.tabview.tab("CTkTabview"), dynamic_resizing=False,
                                                        values=["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value Long Long Long"])
        self.optionmenu_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.combobox_1 = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self.tabview.tab("CTkTabview"),
                                                    values=["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value Long....."])
        self.combobox_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        self.string_input_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("CTkTabview"), text="Open CTkInputDialog",
                                                           command=self.open_input_dialog_event)
        self.string_input_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))
        self.label_tab_2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.tabview.tab("Tab 2"), text="CTkLabel on Tab 2")
        self.label_tab_2.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        # create radiobutton frame
        self.radiobutton_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.radiobutton_frame.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")
        self.radio_var = tkinter.IntVar(value=0)
        self.label_radio_group = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=self.radiobutton_frame, text="CTkRadioButton Group:")
        self.label_radio_group.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="")
        self.radio_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self.radiobutton_frame, variable=self.radio_var, value=0)
        self.radio_button_1.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")
        self.radio_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self.radiobutton_frame, variable=self.radio_var, value=1)
        self.radio_button_2.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")
        self.radio_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkRadioButton(master=self.radiobutton_frame, variable=self.radio_var, value=2)
        self.radio_button_3.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=10, padx=20, sticky="n")

        # create slider and progressbar frame
        self.slider_progressbar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, fg_color="transparent")
        self.slider_progressbar_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")
        self.slider_progressbar_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.slider_progressbar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.seg_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkSegmentedButton(self.slider_progressbar_frame)
        self.seg_button_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(20, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")
        self.progressbar_1 = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(self.slider_progressbar_frame)
        self.progressbar_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(20, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")
        self.progressbar_2 = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(self.slider_progressbar_frame)
        self.progressbar_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=(20, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")
        self.slider_1 = customtkinter.CTkSlider(self.slider_progressbar_frame, from_=0, to=1, number_of_steps=4)
        self.slider_1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(20, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ew")
        self.slider_2 = customtkinter.CTkSlider(self.slider_progressbar_frame, orientation="vertical")
        self.slider_2.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5, padx=(10, 10), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ns")
        self.progressbar_3 = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(self.slider_progressbar_frame, orientation="vertical")
        self.progressbar_3.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=5, padx=(10, 20), pady=(10, 10), sticky="ns")

        # create scrollable frame
        self.scrollable_frame = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(self, label_text="CTkScrollableFrame")
        self.scrollable_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")
        self.scrollable_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.scrollable_frame_switches = []
        for i in range(100):
            switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=self.scrollable_frame, text=f"CTkSwitch {i}")
            switch.grid(row=i, column=0, padx=10, pady=(0, 20))
            self.scrollable_frame_switches.append(switch)

        # create checkbox and switch frame
        self.checkbox_slider_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        self.checkbox_slider_frame.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=(20, 20), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")
        self.checkbox_1 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame)
        self.checkbox_1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(20, 0), padx=20, sticky="n")
        self.checkbox_2 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame)
        self.checkbox_2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(20, 0), padx=20, sticky="n")
        self.checkbox_3 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=self.checkbox_slider_frame)
        self.checkbox_3.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=20, padx=20, sticky="n")

        # set default values
        self.sidebar_button_3.configure(state="disabled", text="Disabled CTkButton")
        self.checkbox_3.configure(state="disabled")
        self.checkbox_1.select()
        self.scrollable_frame_switches[0].select()
        self.scrollable_frame_switches[4].select()
        self.radio_button_3.configure(state="disabled")
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.set("Dark")
        self.scaling_optionemenu.set("100%")
        self.optionmenu_1.set("CTkOptionmenu")
        self.combobox_1.set("CTkComboBox")
        self.slider_1.configure(command=self.progressbar_2.set)
        self.slider_2.configure(command=self.progressbar_3.set)
        self.progressbar_1.configure(mode="indeterminnate")
        self.progressbar_1.start()
        self.textbox.insert("0.0", "CTkTextbox\n\n" + "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\n\n" * 20)
        self.seg_button_1.configure(values=["CTkSegmentedButton", "Value 2", "Value 3"])
        self.seg_button_1.set("Value 2")

    def open_input_dialog_event(self):
        dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Type in a number:", title="CTkInputDialog")
        print("CTkInputDialog:", dialog.get_input())

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)

    def sidebar_button_event(self):
        print("sidebar_button click")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

I tried adding adding additional parameters to the default values, which didn't work and also tried to print out the button name (text="name") in the def sidebar_button_event(self):  print(text) but that didn't work either.  I was hoping that it would give me a clue to the button pressed, but it just printed out ".".

Comment: Show what you have tried on *"I tried adding additional parameters to the default values"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can edit your `sidebar_button_event` function ever so slightly to include another argument, such as the button number, and simply pass that argument through a lambda function when the button is clicked.  It would look like this:

First redefine the `sidebar_button_event`:

```
def sidebar_button_event(self, buttonNum):
        print(f"sidebar_button {buttonNum} click") # don't miss the f (formatted string)
```

And then edit your buttons as such:

```
self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=lambda: self.sidebar_button_event(1))
self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=lambda: self.sidebar_button_event(2))
```

I left the third button out both because it is disabled when you launch the program and to give you some practice if you want to enable it, but this will print to the console what button you are clicking!  Enjoy Python! :)

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Not quite sure if I want to have one handle for all or one for each event.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you needed to hang one handler on two buttons. But you can create your own handler for each button and call the desired method from them

```
self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, 
    command=self.sidebar_button_event_1)
self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, 
    command=self.sidebar_button_event_2)
...

def sidebar_button_event(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print("sidebar_button click")
    print(args, kwargs)

def sidebar_button_event_1(self):
    self.sidebar_button_event("btn 1")

def sidebar_button_event_2(self):
    self.sidebar_button_event("btn 2")
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure which way I'm going to go, both are good.